# Can I imply “kind” or “type” instead of explicitly writing it?

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

There are 5 English books and 5 French books. Can I say “there are two books” instead of “there are two types of books”?

For example:

> There are grapes and an apple, and there are two (kinds of) fruits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

It works with fruit because fruit is uncountable: when we make a plural from an uncountable noun, it specifically means different types of something. So, sugars means different kinds of sugar, glues means different kinds of glue.

For countable nouns, when we make a plural, we mean multiple units of the same thing. So two books only means two books; it doesn't mean two kinds of book.

Note that, "types of..."  and "kinds of...: is always followed by a singular noun. "types of book"